# When is the centralizer of a subset a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, commutative-algebra

**Problem:** Let $G$ be a group with subset $S\subseteq G$. Define the *centralizer* of $S$ to be the set $$C(S)=\{g\in G: gs=sg \mathrm{\;for\;all\;}s\in S\}.$$ When is $C(S)$ a subgroup of $G$?

**Remarks:** My initial thought is to say that $C(S)\leq G \iff S\leq G$. However, I can't prove this equivalence. The trouble is starting to make me think that there is a counter-example floating out there that disproves it, but I haven't been able to produce such an example. My other intuition is that this might only be true if $S$ is a normal subgroup. To that end, I was hoping I could get some help figuring this problem out.

All answers are appreciated.

Comment: $C(S)=\bigcap_{s\in S}C(s)$.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that... Thanks for helping me out! I appreciate it!

Comment: Directly: $(gh)s=g(hs)=g(sh)=(gs)h=(sg)h=s(gh)$ for $g,h\in C(S)$.

Comment: Also, $C(S) = C(\langle S\rangle)$.